# How can I publish my application at Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

I have made an application for computing power indices in cooperative game theory.
I wanted to publish it at the Google Play Console as a paid application, but I got stuck very soon.
I do not know which files that I've created in Android Studio (I have actually 2 relevant: MainActivity.java and acitivity_main.xml) should I upload there and at which place exactly. The rules of Google I just too complicated for me to follow them. Can I get any help from users here ?

Comment: You gotta sign your build and upload an app bundle aab. https://orangesoft.co/blog/how-to-publish-an-android-app-on-google-play-store

Comment: Go through it  : https://play.google.com/console/about/ and the other link mentioned by enviro apps